# PX.Data.XLSXReader not reading first row

Tags: acumatica

I'm using the XLSXReader to read an Excel file, but it is failing to read the first row. I need to read the first row since it contains data and not headers.

Using test data, I put in a blank first row, but it still skipped the first row with data:

[image]

I copied the first row and duplicated it and it read the row:

[image]

I don't know why it is automatically skipping the first row.

Here is the action button code that imports the file, saves it, and reads it:

```
    public PXAction<PMProject> importCostBudget;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Import Cost Budget")]
    protected void ImportCostBudget()
    {
        if (ImportCostBudgetView.AskExt() == WebDialogResult.OK)
        {
            const string PanelSessionKey = "ImportCostBudget";
            PX.SM.FileInfo info = (PX.SM.FileInfo)PX.Common.PXContext.SessionTyped<PXSessionStatePXData>().FileInfo[PanelSessionKey];
            Byte[] bytes = info.BinData;
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(PanelSessionKey);

            if (info != null)
            {
                PXNoteAttribute.AttachFile(Base.Project.Cache, Base.Project.Current, info);                 

                using (PX.Data.XLSXReader reader = new XLSXReader(bytes))
                {
                    //List<PMCostBudget> costBudgets = new List<PMCostBudget>();
                    reader.Reset();

                    //This is to read the first row
                    RowRead(reader);

                    while (reader.MoveNext())
                    {
                        RowRead(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way I can force read the very first row using the reader?

Comment: Last time I checked the class was hardcoded to use first row as the header/column names row.

Comment: Alright, I will inform my customer of the limitations of the reader. I only asked because I saw other sources saying that using the reader, one must manually skip the first row. I guess the reader has changed since that was written by Sergey.

Comment: From memory the headers (first row) are accessed in a different collection and the read method returns the second row the first time it's called after reset.

Comment: Is there any way to access the first row from memory?

Comment: I meant from what I recall :) I'll check source code to try to identify the collection.

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header row is likely treated as a special case intended for reading column names.

You should be able to access it from the XLSXReader IndexKeyPairs collection:

```
public IDictionary<int, string> IndexKeyPairs
{
    get { return _header; }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks! It's off that if I use the GetValue function on the first row, before using MoveNext(), it still gets the row 2nd row.

Comment: Yeah not a fan of the pattern. You'll need to read the first row with a different mechanism (IndexKeyPairs) as I believe GetValue is hardcoded to start from second row as the lower bound.